# SQL Checksum_agg(Checksum(columns)) returns same value for different datasets

Tags: sql, sql-server, checksum, hashbytes

I have multiple tables in one database that I use to compare to an offline access database and see if this offline access database matches any of these predetermined tables. The tables are all identical in structure but contain different values; I'll make it simple by only utilizing one column "Setpoint".

I was using this snippet of code:

```
USE OvenGroups
EXECUTE sp_MSforeachtable '
Insert Into #TempChecksum (CheckSumResults, ProfileName)
Select CHECKSUM_AGG(Checksum([Setpoint]), SUBSTRING("[?]", 10, len("[?]")-12)
From ?
With (NOLOCK)
'
```

To create a checksum of the tables I have in my database and then compare them to each other.
This was working great until I compared two tables that had totally different values in [Setpoint] and got the same checksum back:

```
Table1:Table2  
170:120  
170:120  
180:135  
180:135  
200:155  
200:155  
220:235  
220:235  
255:255  
255:255  
180:220  
180:220
```

(The rest of the two tables share identical values)

```
Results:  
CheckSum    Table Name  
1130627072  6Z13A  
1130627072  TestTest
```

Now I dont really understand how those two completely different datasets would return a different checksum but I am now using a CHECKSUM_AGG(Cast(HASHBYTES()as int) to get my checksum and I am comming up with unique values:

```
USE OvenGroups
EXECUTE sp_MSforeachtable '
--minusovbious has everything execpt the previous setpoint vaule
Insert Into #TempChecksum (CheckSumResults, ProfileName)
Select CHECKSUM_AGG(Cast(HASHBYTES(''SHA2_256'', CONCAT_WS(''|'', [Setpoint], (all my other columns), SUBSTRING("[?]", 10, len("[?]")-12)
From ?
With (NOLOCK)
'
```

Results:

```
CheckSum    Table Name  
-631830728  TestTest  
-1375519242 6Z13A
```

Is this an appropriate solution? Will this return different results for tables? Am I missing something? Is there a better way to compare multiple columns in a table to other tables?